# How to select multiple values in one field MySQL?

Tags: mysql

| id | nama_user | kode_cabang | kode_wilayah | kode_jalan |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | jon | 01 | 03 | 01 |
| 2 | jin | 01 | 03 | 01 |
| 3 | jun | 01 | 03 | 04 |
| 4 | siz | 01 | 03 | 02 |
| 5 | suz | 01 | 03 | 03 |

I have a database like above. I want to return `jon,jin,siz,suz` values in `nama_user` field.

How can I select from mytable where kode_cabang=01 and kode_wilayah=03 and kode_jalan = 01,02,03

Comment: What do you have so far? Show us some code

Comment: What do you mean by multiple values in one field? Do you want to receive a single row with all values concatenated using a comma?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` to get values in one columns

like below

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(nama_user) as nama_user from table_name 
where kode_cabang = 01 and kode_wilayah = 03 and kode_jalan  IN (01,02,03)
```

it will return single row concat name by comma.

Answer (score 1):

Use `IN`

```
select nama_user from table_name where kode_cabang = 01 and kode_wilayah = 03 
and kode_jalan  IN (01,02,03)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(nama_user) as nama_user 
from table_name 
where kode_cabang = "01" 
and kode_wilayah = "03" 
and (kode_jalan="01" or kode_jalan="02" or kode_jalan="03")
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use IN operator like:

```
... WHERE ... AND kode_jalan  IN ('01', '02, '03');
```

Some resources:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `or` operator

```
select nama_user from table_name where kode_cabang = 01 and ode_wilayah = 03 and (kode_jalan = 01 or kode_jalan = 02 or kode_jalan = 03)
```